# jquery/javascript menu issue .siblings() .toggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have coded a 3 level drop down menu in jquery and everything is working perfectly except for when I collapse the top level, it doesn't collapse the third level, i.e.:

```
level 1
level 2
level 3
```

when I collapse it I get:

```
level 1
level 3
```

when it should read:

```
level1
```

I understand you can do this using the silbing function, but I then run into problems because I am using a toggle class as well to change an arrow either facing right or down depending on whether or not the menu is open. It closes the two sub menu levels, but doesn't toggle them so when you reopen that menu the arrows are still facing down when they should be facing right.

Here is my source:

```
$(function() {
    $("li.level2").hide();
    $("li.level3").hide();

    $("ul.navigation").delegate(".level1", "click", function() {
        var item=$(this);
        $(this).nextUntil(".level1", ".level2", ".level3").toggle();
        $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
    });

    $("ul.navigation").delegate(".level2", "click", function() {
        var item=$(this);
        $(this).nextUntil(".level2",".level3").toggle();
        $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
    });
});
```

[Jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qM62Z/). Basically green is level 1 orange is level 2 and red is when the menu is open, if you click on "algebra" and then "year 11" so 2 sub menus are open then click on algebra again it doesn't close the submenus under year 11, and when you use .siblings() the toggle function isn't activated so when you click on "algebra" again to reopen it, "year 11" is read because it hasn't been toggled.

Comment: are you able to modify the HTML of your menus or are you stuck with the given structure?

Comment: yes i can modify the structure to anything

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try nested the UL's? Something like:

```
<ul class="level1">
    <li>level1</li>
    <li>Level1
        <ul class="level2">
            <li>Level2</li>
            <li>Level2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
<ul>
```

That way you can just hide and show the `.children()`, without having to use `nextUntil()` etc. It makes the Javascript a lot easier, and is more semantically correct markup.

Comment: i thought that if you did this you would have to write a lot more classes. ie, one class for each of the <ul>'s if this is possible though i would really appreciate it if you could maybe make a tiny demo of it using 3 levels in jsfiddle, my coding abilities in jquery are next to none, and it took me 3 days with a lot of help to get it to the stage its at now =(

Comment: Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/sjkyZ/ Super basic example, I haven't done the toggle classes, but it shows how simple it can be with nesting.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sjkyZ/1/ so i did a bit of editting, and it works perfectly! thanks, except the highlight is a bit buggy, i was wondering maybe if you could take a look =)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("ul.navigation").delegate(".level1", "click", function() {
    var item=$(this);
    $("li.level2, li.level3").hide();
    $('li.level1').removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).nextUntil(".level1", ".level2", ".level3").toggle();
    $(this).addClass("highlight");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qM62Z/6/

Comment: has the same problem as before, except now it is showing the second class menu ie. level 1 level 2 level 2 instead of level 1 level 3 level 3 which was in the original example compared to just level 1 which i kind of want it to do. the toggle problem also still exists :(

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using divs instead. Notice that your classes are only being used for styling - the javascript does not (and should not) care about them.

http://jsfiddle.net/qM62Z/8/

```
$(function() {
    $(".level2").hide();
    $(".level3").hide();

    $(".navigation").on("click", "div", function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("highlight").children("div").toggle();

        // prevent the event from propogating and collapsing other menus
        return false;
    });
}); ​
```

Comment: thanks for the reply jbabey, i'll check it out tonight when im home form work